# Antecedent of "it" in "it fared with him as with the storm-tossed ship" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns, antecedents

> When on that shivering winter's night, the Pequod thrust her vindictive bows into the cold malicious waves, who should I see standing at her helm but Bulkington! I looked with sympathetic awe and fearfulness upon the man, who in mid-winter just landed from a four years' dangerous voyage, could so unrestingly push off again for still another tempestuous term. The land seemed scorching to his feet. Wonderfullest things are ever the unmentionable; deep memories yield no epitaphs; this six-inch chapter is the stoneless grave of Bulkington. Let me only say that **it** fared with him as with the storm-tossed ship, that miserably drives along the leeward land.

What does the bolded *it* refer to here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no antecedent in the foregoing passage, nor is one required. 
This is the same indeterminate "it" as when you ask your friend **"How is *it* going?"**  "It" is a vague concept that can encompass "life", "fortune", "the universe"...

Answer (score 7):

The "it" has no antecedent. It's being used in the same way as in "it turned out that.." or "it so happened that...", or even "it rained yesterday". The "it" in those sentences has no antecedent. The actual wording of the passage "it fared with him" is a very old-fashioned way of saying "it was his fate". He was destined to end up like a ship sailing too close to a leeward shore in a storm - that is, he was heading for destruction.

Comment: +1 Within the sentence, it's a bare expletive pronoun, as in "it rained". But in the larger context it's an expletive pronoun as in a cleft construction, representing a *postcedent* which is the entire remainder of the chapter.

Comment: +1: Exactly. It's the same as saying *"How goes it with you?"* to enquire how someone is getting along.

Comment: This is often called the “weather it.”

Comment: In fact, *"How fares it with you?"* would have been as common a question at one time (and still is among the elderly in some antique-ish regional dialects).

Comment: @username901345 "In that gale" is a reference to the previously-mentioned storm.

Comment: The last sentence in the passage you quoted in your original question contains a reference to a "storm-tossed ship". It's only seven words away from the "it" you were asking about.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it means that he endured the same fate as the 'storm-tossed ship'. And since the previous sentence mentions a 'stoneless grave' one supposes that both came to a watery end.

Who is the author, and what is the work?

Comment: It's *Moby Dick.*

Comment: I think this is the right answer; but you could mention that *it* here is the "dummy *it*" which doesn't actually refer to anything specific at all. *It* here is simply a marker for Bulkington's situation, which was the same as the storm-tossed ship. Unless you didn't mean that at all, of course.

Comment: @username901345 Because I misunderstood the question, before it was edited.

Answer (score -1):

I found the entire 6 inch chapter for context, and highlighted what I feel is relevant.

To me it's apparent that **it** is the land that *seemed scorching to his feet*. The land could only flirt with him but never draw him in, just as it could never lure the ship to its crunchy shores.

> Some chapters back, one Bulkington was spoken of, a tall, new-landed
>   mariner, encountered in New Bedford at the inn.
>
> When on that shivering winter's night, the Pequod thrust her
>   vindictive bows into the cold malicious waves, who should I see
>   standing at her helm but Bulkington! I looked with sympathetic awe and
>   fearfulness upon the man, who in mid-winter just landed from a four
>   years' dangerous voyage, could so unrestingly push off again for still
>   another tempestuous term. **The land seemed scorching to his feet.
>   Wonderfullest things are ever the unmentionable; deep memories yield
>   no epitaphs; this six-inch chapter is the stoneless grave of
>   Bulkington. Let me only say that it fared with him as with the
>   storm-tossed ship, that miserably drives along the leeward land.** The
>   port would fain give succor; the port is pitiful; in the port is
>   safety, comfort, hearthstone, supper, warm blankets, friends, all
>   that's kind to our mortalities. But in that gale, the port, the land,
>   is that ship's direst jeopardy; she must fly all hospitality; one
>   touch of land, though it but graze the keel, would make her shudder
>   through and through. With all her might she crowds all sail off shore;
>   in so doing, fights 'gainst the very winds that fain would blow her
>   homeward; seeks all the lashed sea's landlessness again; for refuge's
>   sake forlornly rushing into peril; her only friend her bitterest foe!
>
> Know ye, now, Bulkington? Glimpses do ye seem to see of that mortally
>   intolerable truth; that all deep, earnest thinking is but the intrepid
>   effort of the soul to keep the open independence of her sea; while the
>   wildest winds of heaven and earth conspire to cast her on the
>   treacherous, slavish shore?
>
> But as in landlessness alone resides the highest truth, shoreless,
>   indefinite as God - so, better is it to perish in that howling
>   infinite, than be ingloriously dashed upon the lee, even if that were
>   safety! For worm-like, then, oh! who would craven crawl to land!
>   Terrors of the terrible! is all this agony so vain? Take heart, take
>   heart, O Bulkington! Bear thee grimly, demigod! Up from the spray of
>   thy ocean-perishing - straight up, leaps thy apotheosis!

Comment: We don't delete answers simply because the questioner decided that they are not the best answer. There is no "correct" answer, and the answers that you haven't accepted will remain here for future readers.